# Loop not working properly in batch file taking last record

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which takes the input from a csv file having multiple record and continuously update the data in a web site. The code of my script is:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1=0
for /F "tokens=1-2* delims=," %%a in (pwd.csv) do (
    set var2=0
    set array[!var1!][!var2!]=%%a
    set /a var3=var2+1
    set array[!var1!][!var3!]=%%b
)
echo  %array[0][0]%  : %array[0][1]% 
echo
set /a var1+=1 
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
START msedge "https://fams.abc.com/data.faces"
%SendKeys% "%array[0][0]%"
timeout /t 2
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "%array[0][1]%"
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
```

The content of the `pwd.csv` file is:

> ```
> 111, aaaa  
> 222, bbbb  
> 333, cccc  
> 444, dddd
> ```

I want this batch file to upload all these record one by one  but it is taking only last record (`444, dddd`). What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Why are you not providing a proper representative example of the content of the csv file? Please don't try to guess which information you can fake and still get working solutions with your real world data. For your code to act on every combination of login on the site, you'd need to invoke the srndkeys stuff within the loop, not after it. Probably using `Call` would be easier in this case.

Comment: @Compo is there any problem with this data

Comment: Yes, it is not correct for a normal csv, and does not match your provided code.

Comment: @Compo there are two column in csv and it is there . delim is , and it is there in code  and name of the file is pwd.csv.Can u explain, wht is wrong in this so that i can make it clear to you.

Comment: Please look at the csv file you have submitted, and the text where you show the last record again. It is NOT delimited by commas only, is it? It may also be a good idea if you explain to us which specific characters may or may not exist in any field of a record too.

Comment: @Compo I have updated both ,Now can u help me out

Comment: Not only are you still using `111, aaaa` instead of the much more likely `111,aaaa`, or almost as likely `"111","aaaa"`, you have not told us about the possible characters contained in the records, AND, I've already explained to you what your code issue is, and a method you can use to fix it.

Comment: @Compo problem is not with the data.I t is in the correct form,I t may be typing error.Data of the csv columns are alphanumeric. have u explained me my code issue ?

Comment: Go to my very first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330010/loop-not-working-properly-in-batch-file-taking-last-record?noredirect=1#comment129503404_73330010), and carry on reading after learning about your incorrect data... Also, there should not be, and I'll try to be delicate here, a space character after the comma in your csv, the fields of each record are supposed to be comma separated, not a sequence of comma and space sparated. Also, this specific characters abd language set do you count as alpha'

Comment: @Compo CAN U EXPLAIN HOW TO invoke the srndkeys stuff

Comment: Place the sendkeys stuff into a labelled section and `Call` that section using the appropriate arguments, from within the loop.

Comment: may i request you  for the code bcs i could not get what u mean.

Comment: No, I'm not writing your code for you.

Comment: @Compo I am not asking for that complete code Just a hint please,because what ever u have explained so far not enough for me to understand

Comment: No, I have already done that. It is clear that you are using code that you have no idea about how it works. You have not written it, and if somebody else does it all for you now, you will carry on expecting others to do everything for you for the rest of your life.

Comment: @Compo It is not like that actually I am very new to Batch file. If you think like that its fine.Thanks for yoy guidance

Comment: Okay, tell me what your for loop is doing.

Comment: It has to upload the data row by row  but it is uploading the last record only .

Comment: I asked what it was doing, not what you want it to do. Please try to understand it, because that is the main part of your code which is not doing what you need it to do.

Comment: I told  you  that it uploads the data of last row  only (end of loop)  instead of uploading one by one of complete CSV file

Comment: It is not uploading anything, it is in simple terms defining up to two variables, for each non empty line of your file, each overwriting the previously defined one. When the loop ends there are two existing variables, defined, and those are for the last non empty line. Clearly you need to invoke your 'upload' after each line has been read, and before the next is.

Comment: I am not able to invke the upload after every line. Can u tell how can i do that plz

Comment: Yes, invoke the site load and sendkeys after each record has been parsed, but before the next is, instead of doing it after the entire file has been parsed, and closed.

Comment: @Compo I am not able to to do invoking the webload after every record. My web upload is invloked at the last till that time all previous records are wverwritten. How can i invoke the web upload after every record.

Comment: Your code would need to rewrtten by me to solve your issue, and I'm unable to offer that service without having a complete understanding of the allowable characters in each field of each record of your csv file, and clarification on its exact layout. Sorry, but with the information you've provided, I'm unable to offer robust solutions. Of course, the question of why you're logging into a site using multiple identities, is obviously concerning too.

Comment: it is a bulk  data entry  batch file. There  are two column in csv file and  both the column have alpha numeric data (maximum 20 character/numbers).I am not using it to  logging it into any site.Actually in my office i have to make multiple data entry using data from a excel sheet .I want to automate this by using the batch file. I will convert that excel sheet in csv and run that batch file so that it will upload my all data and will save my time. I think  now it is clear @Compo

Comment: Your password, `pwd` CSV data, had email addresses in the second field of each record initially, it's there to see in the revision history. You are opening a single web page in Microsoft Edge, then entering the content of the first field into an input box, allowing two seconds for the next input box to appear before entering the email address/second field data in that. What happens then? And "characters" does not answer my question, I'd need to know which possible language/character set range, and what type of encoding your csv data was saved in too.

Comment: @Compo What u mean ?

Comment: This is not a batch file to login with credential It is used to update my inventory. The first column is used to store the name and the second is used to store the value of that item. This is plain text and number

Comment: So, is it a bulk data entry for your office, or are you uploading information from your game? And as I've said far too many times, the data you've posted is not in the format output from an Excel CSV export. And I want to know which characters can exist in those fields, only the letters of the English alphabet? If not please specify non English and non alpha/numeric, especially characters like `!`, `%` `|` `&` `<` `>` `"` `*` `^` etc.

Comment: I told you its It is for inventory name of the items are plain text and price is in number.

Comment: Here's some plain text, `Luís, João & Zoë spent £14.20 at "Café Z*ne"`. I have no idea which possible characters or in which languages all of your items may contain. If you don't know the difference between my question and plain text, and still have zero idea what the CSV file format really looks like, it is not possible for me to help. All you have to do is open the CSV file in a 'plain' text editor, copy its content, paste it into a code box in your question, and obfuscate any privacy related strings replacing them only with characters already used in your content.

Comment: You are asking a lot of question, You don't want to help me out. Instead of any solution   you are trying to show off your knowledge. I don't know why are you making this  that much complicated. Though I am new to batch file but not new to programming. My simple question is while using for loop in  batch scripting and importing input from any test/csv file i want to do some operation after every row by using the data from that row as variable.

Comment: What you need to understand is that answer code is only any good if the data submitted is as good. You don't need to answer my questions, you could just keep on deliberately using fake and incorrect data, then hope someone wants to answer it. Then they can sit and wait for you to complain that their code fails due to your data, formatting, language, encoding, or something else you omitted to tell us. Nobody wants to do that, and I've already clearly explained that what you're showing as CSV content is nothing Excel would ever create, unless you deliberately manipulated the data.

Comment: I've already told you more than once, that you need to move your commands into the loop, so that they can be run between lines, or `Call` them from there instead. So please continue to deny that I've offered help, just because you don't want to research and try them. If you are expecting more complete service, be prepared to provide information to people willing to do that.

Comment: @Compo i have figured out that problem but now new problem has started .I am asking that in a new question .Your help in that is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If that question contains the same code, or looks anything like this existing and still open one, I will close it again, like I did your last duplicated question. If this question has been solved, please use the answer area to show your solution. Or are going to continue to take our help, but not give anything back.

Comment: @Compo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345736/send-key-not-working-inside-for-loop-in-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem is

1. The task which is to executed should be inside the loop.
   2.Delayed variables are referenced with !var! instead of %var% to avoid  "delayed expansion trap"

the correct code for this is

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then  
    @echo off  
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
    set var1=0  
    for /F "tokens=1-2* delims=," %%a in (pwd.csv) do (  
    set var2=0  
    set array[!var1!][!var2!]=%%a  
    set /a var3=var2+1  
    set array[!var1!][!var3!]=%%b  
    echo  %array[0][0]%  : %array[0][1]%   
    echo  
    set /a var1+=1   
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"  
    START msedge "https://fams.abc.com/data.faces"  
    !SendKeys! "%array[0][0]%"  
    timeout /t 2  
    !SendKeys! "{TAB}"  
    !SendKeys! "%array[0][1]%"  
    !SendKeys! "{ENTER}" 
)
pause
    goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```